# PhpStorm not recognizing $. as jQuery

Tags: jquery, phpstorm

Everywhere I use `$.` to call a jQuery function PhpStorm reports a warning "missing import statement". The jQuery library has been loaded.

Comment: I assume the `jQuery` library is linked to the files in your project, am i right?

Comment: `ctrl+click` on `$` - what file are you taken to? looks as if you have some library that exports `$`, so the IDE suggests to import it

Comment: Wich librairie you loaded, the one from jquery web site or the one from phpstorm community plugins. Cause i had same problem myself and jetbrains support told me to load community plugin.

Comment: I have noticed that it is always the $.ajax function that throws this. When I ctrl+click it says it is looking in datatable.colreorder.js. I have no idea why.
How do I load the community plugin?

Comment: You can mark the `datatable.colreorder.js` file as `Plain Text` or you can probably configure your `.eslintrc.js` so `jQuery` is properly resolved. The first one is probably easier.

Comment: Another option is to explicitly define `const $ = jQuery` in every JavaScript file  which depends on `jQuery`